# Slingshot Issue

Tags: release-loki, slingshot, app-shortcuts

So I came across this issue when I installed a recent application (Packet Tracer7.0 [CISCO]). When I run it trew the sh file on it's folder it works properly well and shows the respective icon on the dock. So far so good, but when I go to my slingshot I found it curious that no icon (or desktop entry) was added there and because of this I believe I can't do the action "Add to dock". More interesting was going on to the /usr/share/application folder and finding that many desktop entries not only for this especific app are there but don't show up in the slingshot menu. Any sugestions?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=PacketTracer7
Icon=pt7
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Packet Tracer 7.0
```

Comment: Did you restart your session (logout / login again)?

Comment: Yeah even when I did that the issue sustained :( @lemonslice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure that *pt7.png* icon file exists in */usr/share/pixmaps* folder?

Comment: well it wasn't but eventually I managed to make this generated desktop entry better, by just doing one my self! :) Thx for the help anyways, what I did do was to put the path to executable file with the %U and then the path to the icon that is inside the app directory then changed the categories to my best suit and voila problem solved